# Jquery select a input filed from a form using wildcard selector

Tags: jquery

I would like to select a input field from a form on the fly, which mean, I don't know which form it would be. consider the following code: ( Suppose the input field id is always 'input1' across all forms)

```
$('[id^=myform]').submit(function(){
   var formId = $(this).attr('id');
   var result = $('#' + formId + ' input#inputl').val();
   ...
});
```

I am looking for a better solution for my purpose. Is there any?

Comment: Considering `id` has to be unique in a document, just `#input1` would do the trick.

Comment: @muistooshort - Ahh, I see. Undeleted :) It was late and I was half asleep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using the `name` attribute of the element (having multiple elements with the same ID is invalid in HTML), and making sure those names are kept consistent across forms:

```
$('[id^=myform]').submit(function(){
  var result = $(this).find('[name="email"]').val();
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^=myform]').submit(function(){
   var result = $(this).find('#input1').val();
});
```

Although like commented above. Ids are supposed to be unique across the entire page so you might need to change the id attribute into a name attribute for all of those input fields.